# I lost bought cars around the map and left the server, can I get them back?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought really expensive cars. I left them all over the map, after which I left the server. What happened to my cars? I didn't have any insurance and none of them were destroyed.

1. If the cars were to be towed, where would the cars be towed to?
2. If the cars were to be in garages, are they in specific garages?

Comment: if this helped, perhaps comment/mark as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, by default all cars you purchase come with insurance and if you've bought them you'll have them until you sell them. I would firstly suggest calling your mechanic and speaking with them, see if you can see the car listed at one of your properties (You need to specify this when you purchase a car)

To your questions

1) You can find the location here

[image]

2) Yes, the garage you assigned the car when you purchased it.

There's also a wonderful guide you can find [here](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=471443440) that I used when this happened to me and I had no idea what had happened, hopefully it'll be helpful for you too.